# Resource based API challenges

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm encountering some challenges in resourced-based rest APIs. In this case, APIs should be a resource instead of an action. For instance, in order to get categories list, we have `/categories (GET)` instead of `/getAllCategories` and for creating a new one, we have `/categories (POST)` instead of `/createCategory`. But there are some challenges:

**Challenge 1:**
In creating a product, we have an `init` request in order to initialize the select boxes of the form (like categories list and brands list). By the old method, we send one single request to get all prerequisites of the product creation page. But in resource-based method, we should have `/categories (GET)` and `/brands (GET)` which cause to have 2 requests, instead of one request (seems to be a bad practice and time consuming)

**Challenge 2:** Let's say we have a resource for the payments list. Admin could see all list of payments (by `/payments (GET)`. But each user must be able to see his own payments. How should be the API structure? (If you say `users/payments/1` that would be not true because by changing 1 to 2, he can access other users payments. Also I control the authorization in hooks, so it's not a good idea to check it in the controllers)

**Challenge 3:**
Imagine on one page I get one the product (only product) by `/products/1 (GET)` and on the other page, I want to get product 1 with all details like (brands, comments, reviews, orders etc). How should be the structure of this API?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> (If you say users/payments/1 that would be not true because by changing 1 to 2, he can access other users payments)

No, he can only retrieve what you permit.  The usual approach would to arrange that `/users/payments/1` and `/users/payments/2` each have access control lists to ensure data security.  Typically, an attempt to "anonymously" access a secured resource will produce some variant of a [401 Unauthorized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) response, whereas a request that is authorized with insufficient credentials receives a [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) (or, in some circumstances, [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)).

> Imagine on one page I get one the product (only product) by /products/1 (GET) and on the other page, I want to get product 1 with all details like (brands, comments, reviews, orders etc). How should be the structure of this API?

Two resources - one that provides the summary of the product, another that produces the verbose description.

The spelling of the identifiers doesn't matter:

```
/products/1/verbose
/products/1?verbose
/verbose/products/1
/products/1?verbose=true
/products/1?verbose=INFO
/products/1?verbose=7
```

Those are all *fine*.

> In creating a product, we have an init request in order to initialize the select boxes of the form (like categories list and brands list). By the old method, we send one single request to get all prerequisites of the product creation page. But in resource-based method, we should have /categories (GET) and /brands (GET) which cause to have 2 requests, instead of one request (seems to be a bad practice and time consuming)

That "should" there seems to be pointing the wrong direction - there's no particular reason that you can't send default values in response to the initial query.

The conflict here might be that someone is trying to couple your resource model to your data model.  A review of Mike Amundsen's work on [Web API Design Maturity Modeling](http://amundsen.com/talks/2016-11-apistrat-wadm/2016-11-apistrat-wadm.pdf) may help.

## Edit

> And about third one, init is a verb and not a resource, so it's not a good idea

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initialize

Please observe that the identifier above works exactly as you would expect it to, even though "initialize" is a verb.  See also:

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put

URI are *identifiers;* very similar in nature to variable names.  The machines *don't care* what spellings you use, because the identifiers have no semantic significance

```
GET /4d335e92-9ae9-4bd6-a08a-089f6459a710
```

works just fine, even though `4d335e92-9ae9-4bd6-a08a-089f6459a710` is a verb.

Comment: Thank you. About first one, I handle my accessibility within the hooks (pre-controller hook). So I don't want to check the token in the method). About the second one, what do you mean by `verbos`? Can you give me an example, please? And about third one, `init` is a verb and not a resource, so it's not a good idea.